# download file with nodejs and sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

i want to download file that i upload to the server with node js and framework sailsjs

```
     $scope.download = function(l,n){
    console.log(n);
    var fs = require('fs');
    var http = require('http');
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(n);
    var request = http.get(l, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
    });
}
```

and when i click to download this error message i get:
ReferenceError: require is not defined

in this 2 file : 
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

and i install before fs and http in npm install

thanks for the help

Comment: why do you want to download something you just uploaded?

Comment: Does not have to be that only now I uploaded files, supposedly I have the ability to upload files to the server and I want an option also download all the files I upload

Answer (score 0):

require() method is a method to import other files into your code in node.js.
node.js is server side javascript platform, which means it only runs on the server side. you're trying to write server side code on the client.

I can see you are using angular. if you're trying to make http requests to your server take a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: i want to build this only with nodejs without  angular its posibale?
and i write this in the controller , where you see that i write in the client side i want to learn ... and thanks !

Comment: i suggest you'll study a bit more about sails.js. you dont need to require files in your controllers and why would even consider making http requests inside of your server side? use queries to find data and then pass it to the client.